# Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [908, 9080]

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, convolutional-neural-network, pytorch

I have a dataset, I have reconfigured my tensors as a single 3072 sized line array. I have reconfigured the valid dataset and training dataset. You can find all of the information about my train, valid dataset and their shapes below:

> Train dataset size: 3991
>
> Valid dataset size: 908
>
> Number of classes: 10
>
> Sample pointcloud shape: torch.Size([3072])

I have a test function defined as below,:

```
import torch
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

def test(model, test_loader):    
    # ensure model is in eval mode
    model.eval() 
    y_true = []
    y_pred = []
   
    with torch.no_grad():
        for data in test_loader:
            inputs, target = data['pointcloud'].to(device).float(), data['category'].to(device)
            target = torch.nn.functional.one_hot(target, num_classes=10)
            output_orig = model(inputs)
            # run the output through sigmoid
            output = torch.sigmoid(output_orig)  
            # compare against a threshold of 0.5 to generate 0/1
            pred = (output.detach().cpu().numpy() > 0.5) * 1
            target = target.cpu().float()
            y_true.extend(target.tolist()) 
            y_pred.extend(pred.reshape(-1).tolist())
        
    return accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)
```

As I run this code with:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from tqdm import tqdm, trange

# Setting seeds for reproducibility
torch.manual_seed(0)
np.random.seed(0)

running_loss = []
running_test_acc = []
t = trange(num_epochs, desc="Training loss", leave=True)

for epoch in t:
        loss_epoch = train(model, train_loader, optimizer,criterion)
        test_acc = test(model, valid_loader)
        t.set_description("Training loss = %f test accuracy = %f" % (np.mean(loss_epoch), test_acc))
        t.refresh() # to show immediately the update           
        running_loss.append(loss_epoch)
        running_test_acc.append(test_acc)
```

I get an error message as:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-40645ae42a17> in <module>()
     13 for epoch in t:
     14         loss_epoch = train(model, train_loader, optimizer,criterion)
---> 15         test_acc = test(model, valid_loader)
     16         t.set_description("Training loss = %f test accuracy = %f" % (np.mean(loss_epoch), test_acc))
     17         t.refresh() # to show immediately the update

3 frames
<ipython-input-27-8ed1b7ca6d78> in test(model, test_loader)
     21             y_pred.extend(pred.reshape(-1).tolist())
     22 
---> 23     return accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py in accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred, normalize, sample_weight)
    209 
    210     # Compute accuracy for each possible representation
--> 211     y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
    212     check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
    213     if y_type.startswith("multilabel"):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py in _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
     82     y_pred : array or indicator matrix
     83     """
---> 84     check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred)
     85     type_true = type_of_target(y_true)
     86     type_pred = type_of_target(y_pred)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    332         raise ValueError(
    333             "Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: %r"
--> 334             % [int(l) for l in lengths]
    335         )
    336 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [908, 9080]
```

> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of
> samples: [908, 9080]

I am stucked with this problem for couple of days, if anyone can help I will be really appreciated

Answer (score 3):

The error is caused by the fact that your `y_true` variable is of shape `(908, 10)` (i.e. one hot encoded) whereas your `y_pred` variable is of shape `(9080,)` (since the original array is of shape `(908, 10)` and you reshape it). You therefore should not reshape the array to make sure it keeps the shape of `(908, 10)` to make sure both arrays have the same number of samples. If you then want to calculate the accuracy you should take the argmax over the second dimension (i.e. the number of classes) to get the actual and predicted class before calling `accuracy_score`.